# coffescript: showing image sequentially from a folder

Tags: coffeescript

I am new to CoffeeScript and JavaScript so I am having some trouble displaying some images sequentially in a html file by changing the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag. This is the code I have:

```
#START: Loop to show all the images of the folder
i = 0
show_images = (folder, start_idx, end_idx) ->
  if start_idx <= end_idx
    $('#video')
      .attr 'src', "/media/generated#{folder}generated#{start_idx}.jpg"
    i += 1
    setTimeout ->
      show_images(folder, start_idx+i, end_idx)
    , 50
#START: Loop to show all the images of the folder
```

I believe this fails because CoffeeScript as JavasCript does not run Syncronously, however I haven't been able to figure out how to accoplish the desired task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `i` var. Try this:

```
#START: Loop to show all the images of the folder
show_images = (folder, start_idx, end_idx) ->
  if start_idx <= end_idx
    $('#video')
      .attr 'src', "/media/generated#{folder}generated#{start_idx}.jpg"
    setTimeout ->
      show_images(folder, start_idx+1, end_idx)
    , 1000
#START: Loop to show all the images of the folder
```